# Unique Key Prop - mapping of table rows with edit button

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap

I have mapped out table rows with data from an api call. I also mapped out edit buttons for each row so I could edit that row's data. But I keep running into this error: "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `EditForm`."

On my edit button's onclick function, I'm calling a function that opens a modal that holds another form component inside. I have a key prop when I've mapped so I'm confused to where I need another key prop in my EditForm component..

this is my state and how I'm setting state to map users.person.

```
 const [users, setUsers] = useState({person:[]});

    useEffect(()=>{
        UserService
        .getAll()
        .then(onSuccess)
        .catch(onError);
    },[setUsers]);

    const onSuccess=(res)=>{
        setUsers({person: res})
    }

    const onError=(err)=>{
        alert(err);
    }
```

```
 <tbody>
        {
            users.person && users.person.map((item)=>(
            <tr key={item.id}>
              <td>{item.name}</td>
              <td>{item.login}</td>
              <td>{item.lastActive}</td>
              <td>{item.email}</td>
              <td>{item.supervisor}</td>
              <td>{item.active}</td>
              <td>{item.language}</td>
              <td><Button variant="secondary" onClick={()=>handleEditShow(item)}>
                  Edit
                </Button>
              </td>
            </tr>
            ))
        }
      </tbody>
```

This piece of the code holds the EditForm component where I'm passing in my editUser object.

```
<Modal show={showEdit} onHide={handleEditClose}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>User Editor</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <EditForm user={editUser} key={editUser.id}/>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
```

I thought adding in  `key={editUser.id}` would have appeased react but I'm still getting this error.

Comment: Is it possible that each `item.id` is not unique on `person`?

Comment: each item.id is unique for each person as the id is the primary key coming from the db

Comment: Any typo in `users.person.map()` perhaps? Since each `item` has a `item.name`, It would seem more natural if it was `users.map()` or `people.map()`.

Comment: Let me edit my code to show state.